# Expression to set cell spacing with SQL Report Builder 3.0

Tags: cell, ssrs-tablix, cellspacing, reportbuilder3.0

I want an expression tho show the square box around every entry inside a column.
I am getting a normal table view right now. I just want to seperate each row borders.
.i.e. Cell spacing.
Please help me in using cell spacing with report builder 3.0

Answer (score 0):

In addition to resolve this issue do the following steps:

1. Add one more row above & below to the Data Row & adjust the height for row as 0.2 in(Approximately - Can you add it more as your wishlist).
2. Then set the background Color using the expression where you want to display a square box as follows,

If you want to match any conditions,

```
=Switch(Condition = Value_1, "Red",Condition = Value_2, "#D2D2D2",True, "No Color")
```

otherwise specify color names or code, red, etc.